# Cancel/kill window.setTimeout() before it happens

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a few places where I use the line below to clear out a status, for example.  I have a few of these that hang out for 10 seconds or more and if the user gets clicking around the action can occur at incorrect time intervals.

```
window.setTimeout(function() { removeStatusIndicator(); }, statusTimeout);
```

Is it possible to cancel or kill this with some jQuery or JavaScript code, so I don't have this process hanging around?

Answer (score 455, accepted):

```
var timer1 = setTimeout(function() { removeStatusIndicator(); }, statusTimeout);

clearTimeout(timer1);
```

Comment: window is just the name of the global namespace, so it's not really necessary (for either setTimeout or clearTimeout).

Comment: Since the first parameter to setTimeout is a function and 'removeStatusIndicator()' is a function, you can gain performance (and type less) by simply: var timer1 = setTimeout(removeStatusIndicator, statusTimeout); This avoids the nested function calls.

Comment: and `window.clearTimeout(timer1)` will not work in Node.js. Either just use `clearTimeout(timer1)` or `global.clearTimeout(timer1)`

Comment: @user1944491 There will be no double-invocation: note that @HarleyDave wrote `setTimeout(removeStatusIndicator, ...)`, i.e. the function `removeStatusIndicator` is not called.

Comment: @FrerichRaabe I was just describing what happened in Chrome when I tried it, so... And remember, it may have been altered since my comment...

Comment: Please ignore what @user1944491 is saying -- it's wrong. The function passed to setTimeout is not called twice.

Chrome did not change its behaviour, more likely you screwed up by calling the function `setTimeout( func(), 0 )` rather than `setTimeout( func, 0 )`

Comment: It might be a silly question but how do you call the timer1 function and how to pass parameters into that setTimeout function?

Answer (score 2):

### The Trick

`setTimeout` returns a number:

[image]

### Solution

Take this number. Pass it to the function `clearTimeout` and you're safe:

[image]

## Code:

Whenever you may need to stop a `setTimeout`, store its value in a variable:

```js
const timeoutID = setTimeout(f, 1000);

// Some code

clearTimeout(timeoutID);
```

(Think of this number as the ID of a `setTimeout`. Even if you have called many `setTimeout`, you can still stop anyone of them by using the proper ID.)

Answer (score 0):

The `window.clearTimeout()` should do what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Please explain your answer and give some examples.  A **good answer** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: +1 just because the comment above looks absolutely un-relevant and random to me. The answer looks absolutely fine, it was just posted later, so it's more like a "copy-paste" of the already provided answer.

Comment: -1: This answer from 2016 is missing lots of important detail and says nothing that the accepted answer from 2009 didn't already say.