# How to kill a process in javascript?

Tags: javascript

Let's take an **example** (i am not asking how to cancel/kill a setTimeout at all, i just use it to represent different processing times of different tasks):

```
<div id="content">
</div>

<p>Which color do you prefer ?</p>    
<button id="long" onClick="long_process();">Blue</button>
<button id="short" onClick="short_process();">Red</button>

<script>
  function long_process() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      $('div#content').text('My favorite color is blue');
    }, 10000);
  }

  function short_proccess() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      $('div#content').text('My favorite color is red');
    }, 1000);
  }

  $('button#long').click();
  $('button#short').click();
</script>
```

Regarding this example, you probably know already what i am going to ask, how can we *stop* the *long processing action* if the user launch a *short processing action* which is supposed to take over it ?

In this example, if the favorite color of the user is red, but the user click the wrong (blue) button, then click the red button, the blue color willl be the last color displayed because its process is longer.

I know how to manage it with C/C++ using the pthread library, but i have no idea with javascript, and it's very important in some situation to be 100% sure about what your app will display.

Thanks !

Comment: Shouldn't your question be, how do cancel a setTimeout call?

Comment: @j08691: Agree. MDN Docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.clearTimeout

Comment: No because in my example `setTimeout` replace an action (for example calling a database or whatever you can imagine), the thing is, if A and B interract differently with the same target and A is longer than B (differents actions never get exactly the same time to process), if i want B as result but i launched A just before, how to do it ? (this is exactly my example)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to cancel/kill window.setTimeout before it happens on the client?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/452003/how-to-cancel-kill-window-settimeout-before-it-happens-on-the-client)

Comment: If you're using a loop you can set some flag or invocation id, and if false/mismatch `return;`. This does mean extra ops in the loop -> slower performance. There isn't really such a thing as "threads" in JavaScript, except [web worker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Using_web_workers)s!.

Comment: You can simply discard the process outcome if it isn’t the latest executed one. For this you need to store latest task name and separate task from its outcome. Before applying the outcome check if it is the latest.

Answer (score 2):

When creating a timer, `setTimeout` and `setInterval` return an ID that you can use to reference that timer:

```javascript
var long_timer;

function long_process() {
    long_timer = setTimeout(...);
}
```

When you want to stop that timer, pass that ID into [`clearTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.clearTimeout) or [`clearInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.clearInterval):

```javascript
if (long_timer) {
    clearTimeout(long_timer);
}
```

Comment: -1 as I think the gravity of the question does not lie around the `setTimeout`s. If I am not wrong it is around few asynchronous functions doing some tasks.. and if any of these functions is taking more time than required, then how to stop/kill/abort that function.

Comment: @Goje87: You're welcome to post an answer. With the new edits to the original question, I'm not even sure what OP is asking about anymore.