# How to clear these setTimeouts when function gets called again

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, settimeout, cleartimeout

so I have a function which starts up the same animation in a div when you load up any page/section.

I noticed that while the Arrows are navigating to the next position and I change pages(via Ajax requests) that the Arrows keep animating from it's last position.

[I found this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/452003/how-to-cancel-kill-window-settimeout-before-it-happens-on-the-client), but so far the solution isn't working. Also it seems that I would have to create a global variable for each of the deeper variables to stop them? Seems like I'm doing it wrong :(

```
clearTimeout(arrow1);
clearTimeout(arrow2);
clearTimeout(arrow3);
clearTimeout(arrow4);

$('#answer_request_walkthrough').text('This shows the person requesting an intro to someone.');
$('#arrow1 .fake_arrow').fadeIn('slow');
$('#answer_request_walkthrough').fadeIn('slow', function() {

    // Point Requestor
    var arrow1 = setTimeout(function () {

        var arrow2 = setTimeout(function () {

            // Point Target
            $('#answer_request_walkthrough').fadeOut('fast', function() {
                $('#answer_request_walkthrough').text('This is the person you know, that they would like to meet.');
                $('#answer_request_walkthrough').fadeIn('fast');
            });

            $('#arrow1 .fake_arrow').fadeOut('slow', function() {
                $('#arrow2 .fake_arrow').fadeIn('slow');
            });

            var arrow3 = setTimeout(function () {

                // Point Message
                $('#answer_request_walkthrough').fadeOut('fast', function() {
                    $('#answer_request_walkthrough').text('This is their message detailing why they want to meet the target.');
                        $('#answer_request_walkthrough').fadeIn('fast');
                    });

                    $('#arrow2 .fake_arrow').fadeOut('slow', function() {
                    $('#arrow3 .fake_arrow').fadeIn('slow');
                });

                    var arrow4 = setTimeout(function () {

                        // Point Button
                        $('#answer_request_walkthrough').fadeOut('fast', function() {
                            $('#answer_request_walkthrough').text('Finally Accept or Deny a message, you remain anonymous if you choose to deny.');
                            $('#answer_request_walkthrough').fadeIn('fast');
                        });

                        $('#arrow3 .fake_arrow').fadeOut('slow', function() {
                            $('#arrow4 .fake_arrow').fadeIn('slow');
                        });

                    }, 4000);

                }, 5000);

            }, 5000);

        }, 5000);
    });
```

Update (I'm seeing something strange)
I let the animation start playing and I see arrow1 = 6, arrow2 = 10 etc.. then I start my test by navigating away (Ajax calls) and I see this start to happen and the bug continues to happen:

```
arrow2 = 7 whoat-dash.js:660
arrow3 = 10 whoat-dash.js:655
arrow4 = 13 whoat-dash.js:650
page timers = 6 whoat-dash.js:602
page timers = 7 whoat-dash.js:602
page timers = 10 whoat-dash.js:602
page timers = 13 whoat-dash.js:602
arrow1 = 21 whoat-dash.js:665
page timers = 21 whoat-dash.js:602
arrow1 = 22 whoat-dash.js:665
page timers = 22 whoat-dash.js:602
arrow1 = 23 whoat-dash.js:665
arrow2 = 24 whoat-dash.js:660
arrow3 = 27 whoat-dash.js:655
arrow4 = 30 whoat-dash.js:650
page timers = 23 whoat-dash.js:602
page timers = 24 whoat-dash.js:602
page timers = 27 whoat-dash.js:602
page timers = 30 whoat-dash.js:602
arrow1 = 36 whoat-dash.js:665
arrow2 = 37 whoat-dash.js:660
arrow3 = 40
```

I added a console.log to Travis's code so I could see what happens when I load a new page and thus run's this animation function again:

```
//check for existence of previous timeouts
            if ( typeof($.pageTimers) != "undefined" ) {
            //iterate and clear timers if present
                for( var i = 0; i < $.pageTimers.length; i++ ) {
                    clearTimeout($.pageTimers[i]);
                    console.log('page timers = '+$.pageTimers[i]);
                }
            }
```

Comment: Where are you trying to clear them from?

Comment: just clear them all in your fadeIn function

Comment: When I navigate to a new page, this basically starts over again, but if I navigated away while it was in mid animation, basically 2 animations keep going now.

Comment: I don't understand how the 2 animations "keep going" if you change page navigation

Comment: The setTimers keep going. arrow2 leads into arrow3, when I ajax in the new page.. arrow1 starts over again, but then arrow3 is still there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All setTimeout returns is an integer. If the page is being loaded as a result of ajax, then you are going to be forced to store the information for the timeouts somewhere with global access. Since you are using jQuery, you can attach to that if you do not want to muddy the global namespace.

```
$('#answer_request_walkthrough').fadeIn('slow', function() {

 //check for existence of previous timeouts
 if( typeof($.pageTimers) != "undefined" ){
  //iterate and clear timers if present
  for( var i = 0; i < $.pageTimers.length; i++ ){
   clearTimeout($.pageTimers[i]);
  }
 }
 //reset timeout holder
 $.pageTimers = [];

 //regular code sections


 var arrow1 = setTimeout(function () {
  var arrow2 = setTimeout(function () {

  });
  //push timer int into timeout holder
  $.pageTimers.push(arrow2);
 });
 //push timer int into timeout holder
 $.pageTimers.push(arrow1);
```

Comment: Thanks for the example, I just tried it, but did not work :( I think I need to rebuild my animation, this just seems wrong. Like I shouldn't have to keep indenting like that

Comment: Thanks Travis for posting this update, at first it looked like my bug was fixed, but it's still doing it :( I think I need to rebuild how I'm doing the animations.

Comment: Oh wait it does work! I had to move the reset function outside of that first fadeIn('slow')! `$('#answer_request_walkthrough').fadeIn('slow', function() {` Thanks :D