# show and hide popup in specific situations

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, popup

I have a textbox in my php form in which user can insert a movie title, or an actor/actress name and then by clicking a search button, a new window (movielist.php) will be opened showing list of movies containing that title or movies by that actor/actress.

**Question:**
Since sometimes the query takes a long time (for example if user only type "home", to see all movies contain this word, or if he insert "tom" to see all movies by all actors contain "tom" in their names, it will take a few minutes), I would like to show a message to user if he/she would like to wait more or maybe he prefer to change the search term.

Here is what I tried till now:

```
<body>
<div id="message" div align="center"><img id="loading" src="http://schools.nyc.gov/ui/cms/sites/commoncore/images/loadingAnimation.gif" width="350" height="350">
<br />
Please wait while data is being loaded. 
</div>    
<div id= "field">
</div>
<?php
$pagenumber = '1';
    if(!empty($_GET['page'])) {
       $pagenumber = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'page', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);
        if(false === $pagenumber) {
          $pagenumber = '1';
        }
    }
?>    
 <script type="text/javascript">
(function(){
    setTimeout(showpopup, 10000)
 })();
function showpopup(){
      alert("It may take some time to browse data..Please change your search keywords if you don't want to wait longer");
     }

  $('#message').show();
  var searchType = parent.window.opener.searchType;
  var textbox = parent.window.opener.textbox; 
  var pagenumber = "<?php echo $pagenumber; ?>";

  $.ajax({
         url: 'searchfilm.php', //where I have DB Queries
         datatype: "json",
         data:{q:textbox, t:searchType, page:pagenumber},
         success: function(response) {       
                   $("#field").html(response);
                   $("#message").hide();
                   } 
        });        
</script>    
</body>
```

With the above code, when user insert a term in the textbox and click search, it shows the loading image in the page and opens the pop-up after 10 seconds.

**Problem:**

It shows pop-up in any case, even when query is fast and it shows results (movie list) immediately, the pop-up opens after 10 seconds always. Could someone kindly let me know how can I prevent popup to be opened when results are displayed? Also, Is it possible to show pop up with 2 buttons: "Yes, continue", "No, quit"?

The below image might show my problem better:

[image]

Comment: Sidenote: If your query takes a long time to execute, chances are that your table isn't indexed.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I indexed my tables, and after indexing it became faster.. but still there are some cases that it will takes time (ex: if user type "the" to see all movies contain "the", (also maybe because it shows a small image, it is a bit slower..)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to store the reference to your `setTimeout()` for loading the alert... In your success-method, clear the timeout like outlined in the following SO question:

[How to cancel/kill window.setTimeout before it happens on the client?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/452003/how-to-cancel-kill-window-settimeout-before-it-happens-on-the-client)

Example code (untested):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var popupTimeout = setTimeout(showpopup, 10000);
function showpopup(){
      alert("It may take some time to browse data..Please change your search keywords if you don't want to wait longer");
     }

  $('#message').show();
  var searchType = parent.window.opener.searchType;
  var textbox = parent.window.opener.textbox; 
  var pagenumber = "<?php echo $pagenumber; ?>";

  $.ajax({
         url: 'searchfilm.php', //where I have DB Queries
         datatype: "json",
         data:{q:textbox, t:searchType, page:pagenumber},
         success: function(response) {       
                   $("#field").html(response);
                   clearTimeout(popupTimeout);
                   $("#message").hide();
                   } 
        });        
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works :) Is there also a way to have button in the popup? (so I can ask user to click on "yes, continue" or "No, quit"?

Comment: @mOna Yes ofcourse, but not by using `alert()`. You could look into jQuery-UI dialog objects, or for a simple yes/no into javascript's `confirm()` function.

Comment: Thanks a lot again :), still, I have to wait for 1 more minute to accept your answer ;)

Comment: That's okay, in the meantime, here is a link to the jquery-ui dialog confirm-box: https://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/dialog/modal-confirmation.html

Answer (score 1):

It shows pop-up box, because:

```
function(){
    setTimeout(showpopup, 10000)
})();
```

orders it to do so.

Change it to:

```
var timeoutId;
function(){
    timeoutId = setTimeout(showpopup, 10000)
})();

$.ajax({
     url: 'searchfilm.php', //where I have DB Queries
     datatype: "json",
     data:{q:textbox, t:searchType, page:pagenumber},
     success: function(response) {
               clearTimeout(timeoutId);
               $("#field").html(response);
               $("#message").hide();
               } 
    });
```

Comment: How is this different from the answer I supplied?

Comment: @RichardBernards: he posted this answer just some moments before you edit and post your code ;)

Comment: @mOna My question remains the same... If there is an answer with no examplecode, you should edit the answer, or comment on the answer, instead of trying for the quick win...

Comment: @RichardBernards - stay cool. mOna answered you: I did not saw your answer.

Comment: @MichalWilkowski no sweat... I was asking because there is some slight difference in scoping which could be different from my answer... I was really asking for the difference ;)