# Have a delay when calling a plugin on mouse over, while also canceling on mouse out

Tags: javascript, tooltip

This is not my code, my code cannot easily be isolated for this post so I made a blank page.

I would like to set a delay for the execution of the tooltip plugin (I use a different plugin with no such support and am not allowed to change it).

A simple timeOut will not do the trick, I don't just have to delay the execution of the tooltip script, I also have to abort that execution completely when the user takes the cursor out if a preset time did not completely end.

In other words, there has to be a delay before displaying the tooltip, and also the tooltip must not be displayed at all if the user doesn't keep the mouse over the `.inline_box` long enough.

```js
$('.inline_box').tooltip();
```

```css
.container {
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.col_left {
    width: 100px;
    display: table-cell;
    background: #708A91;
}

.col_mid {
    display: table-cell;
}

.col_mid input {
    width: 100%;
}

.col_right {
    display: table-cell;
    background: #708A91;
}

.col_right .element_with_variable_width {
    padding: 10px
}

.inline_box {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align:  top;
    height:19px;
    width: 30px;
    margin: 0 5px;
    background-color: #E066FF;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div class="container">
    <div class="col_left"></div>
    <div class="col_mid">
        <input type="text">
    </div>
    <div class="col_right">
        <span class="element_with_variable_width">
            <span class="inline_box" title="Some info"></span>
            <span class="inline_box" title="some other info"></span>
            <span class="inline_box" title="Moar info"></span>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cancel the javascript timeout.

So on mouseIn you start timeout and assign it to some variable.
On the mouseOut you just cancel that timeout. [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/452003/how-to-cancel-kill-window-settimeout-before-it-happens-on-the-client)

Comment: I'll try to include that in the custom plugin I use, but the problem is that once `$('.inline_box').tooltip();` is ran, the mouse over action is already bound and will execute instantly.

But I do supposed there is no "magic trick" to fix that, I have to modify the plugin. Thank you.

Comment: What plugin do you use? It is possible that you can configure it.

Comment: It's a custom made plugin, I'm trying to add this functionality to it with your example. Will check back if I succeed.

Comment: Post more code from plugin to question so that people can help you.

Comment: I kept trying, it has over 2000 lines of code :) and I can't get it to work in the code snippet system here. I'll be back when I figure it out, set timeout should do it, I'll try to actually implement this as a parameter for the plugin.

Comment: What I can tell you is that I have a "before callback" option that executes before the tooltip is displayed, and a callback option that executes (if I get all this right) after the tooltip has opened, but before it is closed.

Setting a timeout to pause script execution in "before callback" would probably work, but is it a good practice?