# How to stop redirecting with close button using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4

I want to stop redirecting page with close button. Right now I have situation where user clicks log out button and I displaying modal with message, I've added close button to my modal and I want to achieve that when user clicks close button page doesn't redirect.

My code is:

HTML

```
<li><a href="/logout" id="log"><i class="zmdi zmdi-power"></i> <span>Log out</span></a></li>
```

JS

```
$('#log').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(".close").remove();
            $(this).hide();
            $(".content").append('<div class="card " ><div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade show al"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button>Oh snap! <a href="#" class="alert-link">Change a few things up</a> and try submitting again.</div></div>');
            setTimeout(function () {
                window.location.href = "/logout";
            }, 6000);
        });
```

My modal is closed but still redirects me. Can anybody help me with this?

Comment: What do you mean "still redirects"? Immediately? Because of course it redirects, there's a `window.location` still in there.

Comment: Just remove the `setTimeout(function ... 6000);` part?

Comment: @msg That part needs to stay, what I'm trying to achieve is when user clicks on close button on modal that page stop redirecting.

Comment: So you want the user to logout, but you do not want the page to redirect? In that case you're going to need Ajax.

Comment: @icecub My case is like this: user clicks log out, I'm showing some message via modal (duration 6 seconds). That modal has close button, I'm trying to achieve that, when user clicks close button - they will not be log out.

Comment: Ohwwww, you mean like a cancel button? I'll write you an answer. It's simple to do, but too much code for a comment

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cancel/kill window.setTimeout() before it happens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/452003/cancel-kill-window-settimeout-before-it-happens)

Comment: I know I've answered the question for clerity, but this question is a duplicate so I'm voting to close it for that reason :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To cancel the logout with your "ok" button, you need to change your code like this:

```
var logoutTimer;

$('#log').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".close").remove();
    $(this).hide();
    $(".content").append('<div class="card " ><div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade show al"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button>Oh snap! <a href="#" class="alert-link">Change a few things up</a> and try submitting again.</div></div>');
    doLogout();
});

function doLogout(){
    logoutTimer = setTimeout(function () { window.location.href = "/logout"; }, 6000);
}

function cancelLogout(){
    clearTimeout(logoutTimer);
}
```

Now just call the `cancelLogout()` function with your button:

```
onclick="cancelLogout();"
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

If you do not change href="#" your redirect will initiate. changing it to "#" will wait for 6 seconds, giving you time to kill redirect on close click!

```
<li><a href="#" id="log"><i class="zmdi zmdi-power"></i> <span>Log out</span></a></li>
```

SCRIPT

```
var timer;
function cancelRedirect(){ 
   clearTimeout(timer)
}
$('#log').click(function (e) {
 ...
 timer = setTimeout(function () {
            window.location.href = "/logout";
        }, 6000);
 //On close click call cancelRedirect()
 ...
}
```