# How to set a limit to the execution time of a function in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have an asynchronous javascript function. When that function executes, it can end and return data or it runs forever.
I wanted to limit this function execution, so that if the it hangs, I can stop it after a timeout:

- If it takes less than 10 seconds running (for example, it takes 4 seconds to complete), then it doesn't have to wait 6 seconds to execute the next instructions.
- If it takes more than 10 seconds (in case the function never answers), then I would like to terminate it.

Is there any way to do this without using setTimeout() (because I don't want to wait if the function ends its execution before the timeout)?

Comment: so we talking about promises here?

Comment: yes, I wanted to use promises to achieve this @ProClasic

Comment: currently you can't force stop a promise in vanilla js but it might get added soon.

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing API calls, a library like `axios` provides timeouts options

```
import axios from axios ;

axios
.get(‘url’, {timeout: 3000})
.then((res) => console.log(res))
.catch((err) => console.log(err))
```

Otherwise I think, you can clear/kill timeout before it ends: https://stackoverflow.com/a/452007/10691892

Answer (score 0):

There is no general way to do this.

The closest you could come would be to create a promise and reject it with a `setTimeout` (which you wanted to avoid) but that would still leave the asynchronous process running.

Some asynchronous functions have built-in features for configuring a timeout on them, but they are specific to the particular API and not a general solution.