# Show post saved message with timeout and intervall in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

A WYSIWYG editor has an autosaved option to store text automatically on keyup to the localStorage. I want to display a "post saved" message above the editor, to let the users know, the text is saved.

The "post saved" message that is triggered on `keyup` also, should start first after 20 seconds of writing with an interval of 30 seconds.

The problem is that if you have written, for example, 10 letters, it means  `keyup` events, so the interval is firing 10 times instead of only 1 time.

What I have:

```html
<div id="saved" style="color:green;"></div>
```

```js
setInterval(function() {
  $('#saved').text('[ Post saved ]').show();

  setTimeout(function() {
    $('#saved').fadeOut();
  }, 20000);
}, 30000);
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: You should cancel previous timeout/interval [Cancel/kill window.setTimeout() before it happens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/452003/cancel-kill-window-settimeout-before-it-happens)

Comment: And where do I have to display the kill timeout?